# react-i18next how to translate a given string

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I have a React app that uses `react-i18next` for localization.

I have translated many things like menu titles, button texts etc. But I have some values that are not "hardcoded" per se.

For example, I have something like "Air quality". So I have it translated like

`en.tsx`

```
const LocaleEn = {
  airQuality: 'Air quality'
}
```

`pl.tsx`

```
const LocalePl = {
  airQuality: 'Jakość powietrza'
}
```

Then, I init the `i18next` "instance" like this:

```
i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: LocaleEn,
    },
    pl: {
      translation: LocalePl,
    },
  },
  lng: 'en',
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
  supportedLngs: ['en', 'pl'],
});

export default i18next;
```

Then, it's just `const {t} = useTranslation()` and `t('airQuality')`.

Fairly simple. Now, I want to have a box/div/whatever displaying the "Air Quality" text but also its value. There are two possible values and they are string: `GOOD` and `BAD`.

What I came up with is just having something like:

```
const LocaleEn = {
  airQuality: {
    name: 'Air quality',
    goodValue: 'GOOD',
    badValue: 'BAD'
  }
}
```

And then I'd do something like:

```
const airQuality = 'GOOD'
// [...]
<p>{t('airQuality.name')}</p>
<p>{airQuality === 'GOOD'? t('airQuality.goodValue'): t('airQuality.badValue')}</p>
```

But this is tedious, having this `if`.

So, my question is: is there a way for `react-i18next` to receive something like `GOOD` or `BAD` and translate it - based on the locale selected? With of course me providing those translations somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can do that.

The way that I have found most useful to do these translations is having each word inside of your dictionary of a different language.

By doing translate("GOOD"), If the locale is the default locale, and it is not in that dictionary, it will display the text given. Then inside of your secondary language dictionary, you can make

```
"GOOD": ""
```

a translated value, and when that key is seen, it will use the translated word. That way the dictionary of the other languages are always the english word as a key.

Then inside of your sample, you can do

```
t(airQuality)
```

Each word, or phrase, should have a corresponding translation in the JSON file for every language that is not the default.

In this case an example of your JSON might look like this

```
const LocalePl = {
   "Air Quality": "Jakość powietrza"
   "GOOD": "[translate]",
   "BAD": "[translate]",
}
```

your english translation can be blank.

Your JSX then would look like this:

```
<p>{t("Air Quality")}</p>
<p>{t(airQuality)}</p>
```

Comment: Sorry to get back so late to this question. Yeah, that is also what I thought I could do - just put the "values" (like "GOOD" or "BAD") inside the dictionaries. And that's perfectly fine. It's basically what I did now, but I back then I was just wondering if there's like some other mechanism, so I wouldn't conflate the "hardcoded values" (like menu titles, button texts) with "variables" (the stuff that changes based on user input/conditions). Seeing as it is not possible, its seems that approach you proposed is **the way** to do it, so that's what I'll do.

Comment: Shame that when you don't put the GOOD and BAD in the english dict, it doesn't work with nested keys, like `t('airQuality.GOOD')` - I mean it does, displaying `"airQuality.GOOD` :P The solution is to either have `GOOD` and `BAD` as "root" keys (not really an option, since Polish language has noun declension) or just provide the GOOD and BAD in english dict - that's what ended up doing

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work out for you ?

```
<p>{t(`airQuality.${airQuality.toLowerCase()}Value`)}</p>
```

Comment: Huh, that is basically another way of doing what I did. I would have to maintain that the lowercase values are in fact in my "dictionary".  It could work, sure. I may even end up doing this. However, I wanted to know if maybe `react-i18next` has some dedicated feature for what I want to do. I'll wait, maybe someone knows about something like this. If not - sure, why not :)